# Splitting text into separate rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've pulled off a table of football results from a website and pasted the data into Excel.

One of the rows is in the format: "Brighton - Manchester City". I would prefer to have these split into separate, adjacent rows of "Brighton" in A and "Manchester City" in B. What is my best option for doing this in batch?

I understand I can use regular expressions, but not sure what my options for performing these are on Excel 2016 on Mac.

Comment: Not familiar with Mac versions specifically, but the Windows version of Excel has had a Text to Columns feature for some time. Basically does a similar job to how a CSV file is parsed into columns, but using a column of existing data. I would suggest using this to get three columns, the middle one of which has only "-" characters in, so you then delete this unwanted column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to understand the structure of your data, but as you've described it, I would copy the data and paste it into a document editor

Replace all occurrences of the dash - with a comma ,

Save as csv.

Open in excel

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you :)